# Google SignIn not working for iOS 10

Tags: ios, google-signin, swift4, ios10.3

I have integrated the `GoogleSinIn API` in my project with `Swift 4.0`. It is working on `iOS 11.0` but when I'm testing the same on `iOS 10.0` it is opening the `Google` login page on the `Safari` browser or the device and after signing successfully it is opening the `Google` search page.

1. When I click the `GoogleSignIn` button shown below it opens the browser shown in next image.
2. Then I fill up the credentials.
3. After the successful signed in, It redirects to the `Google` page instead of the application page.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue, Do let me know when you got the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using wrong handler in `AppDelegate`.

**Previously I was using:**

```
private func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool
```

**But it should be:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to implement this delegate function in your `AppDelegate`.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
     return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```

Answer (score 5):

check your `GIDSignInUIDelegate`, don't forget

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: hi, with this method I am able to google sign in. But after sign in, i want to go to drive file list. It is redirecting me to google.com . Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

Google documentation sucks! I'm using iOS 10 and documentation says to add the second method I wrote only if using iOS 8.0 or older. Don't know why. I got success adding these two methods:

```
// [START openurl]
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
  return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
// [END openurl]
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
  sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
  annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {


    BOOL handleGoogleSignIn = [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                         annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
    if (handleGoogleSignIn) {
        return handleGoogleSignIn;
    }
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {

    BOOL handleGoogleSignIn = [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                           sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                  annotation:annotation];
    if (handleGoogleSignIn) {
        return handleGoogleSignIn;
    }
}
```

If you use sourceApplication ,you need write GoogleSignIn return both.